# How can I select only the children attributes with querybuilder using symfony 4?

Tags: api, symfony4

I have a class named "insured object" that have two children "car" and "house" and this "insured object" has a one to one relation to  "contract". The idea is when the user wants to add a contract he must specify its type whether it's a car or a house and add it to the database according to its type. So while working on the APIs (the editing one) a problem occurred, which is when i want to select a car to edit it shows me this error [the error when i execute the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5k8z.png)

this is the car editing API.

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/editVoiture/{id}", name="editVoiture", methods={"PUT"})
*/
public function editVoiture($id, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em,ObjetAssureRepository $objetAssureRepository, VoitureRepository $voitureRepo)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $jsonRecu = $request->getContent();
    try {
        $donnees = json_decode($jsonRecu);
        $voiture = $voitureRepo->findVoitureById($id);
        if($voiture != null){
            $voiture->setDateAcquisition($donnees->dateAcquisition);
            $voiture->setDateProduction($donnees->dateProduction); 
            $voiture->setMarque($donnees->marque);    
            $voiture->setNumChassis($donnees->numChassis);
            $voiture->setPuissance($donnees->puissance);
            $voiture->setModele($donnees->modele);                   
            $em->persist($voiture);
            $em->flush();
            $objAss = $objetAssureRepository->findObjet($voiture->getId(),"voiture");
            $objAss->setDateAcquisition($donnees->dateAcquisition);
            $objAss->setDateProduction($donnees->dateProduction);
            $em->persist($objAss);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response('ok', 200);
        } else {
            return new Response('does not exist',404);
        }
    } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
        return $this->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

and this is the repository code

```
/**
 * @return Voiture
 */
public function findVoitureById($id): ?Voiture
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->andWhere('v.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id',$id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `VoitureRepository` 's `findVoitureById` function?

Comment: i fixed the error, thank you anyways